# Custom font in Qt Creator IDE

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, ubuntu-12.04

I successfully installed Consolas font on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTE as described [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-TrueType-Fonts-on-Ubuntu). It looks great in my terminal app, but Qt Creator IDE does not suggest me to use Consolas in its text editor. More over Qt Creator doesn't see some other system fonts either, but in the same time it has some its own fonts, for example Utopia.

Does somebody know how to make available system fonts in Qt Creator or hardcode additional fonts in custom build of Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Qt Creator from Ubuntu Software Center looks very well and it found all my system fonts. The only drawback is that the latest available version there now is 2.5.

Comment: Just found latest package 2.6.0 of Qt Creator from Ubuntu team here http://goo.gl/ZoC5B. Works like a charm.